# Non-caching npm modules requiring build

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, alpine-linux

I have an automated build set up on linux that never npm caches packages that need node-gyp builds, eg. bcrypt, zmq etc - every time an `npm install` is run these packages build again from scratch, any suggestions?

Here's an example of a build that's re-running on every `npm install`

```
> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /usr/local/bin/buildAgent/work/b6eb772ba309440a/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/bin/buildAgent/work/b6eb772ba309440a/node_modules/bcrypt/build
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
```

I've had similar experiences on ubuntu & alpine (within docker builds), on both x86 and arm.

Comment: As far as I know, the npm cache is just for caching the package files you would download from the NPM registry; it never caches build artifacts.

Comment: That would explain it - I'd mark this as the answer if true! Any workarounds would be nice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pnpm` or `yarn`, I think both may have an option like that kind of caching.

Comment: Good when they work, but both die on my build server - partly due to private repos and not using my .npmrc file. Doubt I'll get much better of an answer though, and by the time someone else reads this they may have their issues resolved.